# upgrade to the centos version of the linux

Tags: linux, centos

how i upgrade cent 6.9 to directly the version of Cent 7.4
urgent required as soon as possible reply as soon as possible

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Downvoted for *"urgent required as soon as possible reply as soon as possible"*.

Answer (score 3):

You don't.  For a major release, perform a fresh installation.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the preupg way (see the linked article)

https://linuxacademy.com/blog/linux/centos-7-upgrading-from-centos-6-x-in-place/

However it's not bulletproof! I wouldn't do it on the production system without proper backup and you may face some dependency problems in case you used additional repos!

But as @DopeGhoti advised, fresh installation is the recommended way.